# IAP error caused rejection but I don't understand what the problem is

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

Here is the message I got for the rejection:
"We found that your in-app purchase products exhibited one or more bugs when reviewed on iPad running iOS 13.2 on Wi-Fi.

Specifically, when we tapped on the purchase button at your store, no purchasing activity was carried out.

Next Steps

When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s test environment. The recommended approach is for your production server to always validate receipts against the production App Store first. If validation fails with the error code "Sandbox receipt used in production," you should validate against the test environment instead."

I can't exactly understand what the problem is. IAP worked fine for me in sandbox so I am guessing I am missing something somewhere. Any help appreciated.

```
        public class IAPManager : MonoBehaviour, IStoreListener
{

    IStoreController controller;
    IExtensionProvider extensions;
    public GameObject iapButton;


    const string gameID = "com.thegame.";

    void Start()
    {
        InitializePurchasing();
        CheckIfNoAdsPurchased();

    }

    public void CheckIfNoAdsPurchased()
    {
        Product product = controller.products.WithID(gameID + "noads");
        if (product != null && product.hasReceipt)
        {
            // Owned Non Consumables and Subscriptions should always have receipts.
            // So here the Non Consumable product has already been bought.
            TheGameCtrl.instance.showAds = false;
            iapButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        }
        else
        {
            TheGameCtrl.instance.showAds = true;
            iapButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        }
    }

    public void InitializePurchasing()
    {
        // If we have already connected to Purchasing ...
        if (IsInitialized())
        {
            // ... we are done here.
            return;
        }
        var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());

        // Use your own products
        builder.AddProduct(gameID + "noads", ProductType.NonConsumable);


        UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
    }

    bool IsInitialized()
    {
        // Only say we are initialized if both the Purchasing references are set.
        return controller != null && extensions != null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when Unity IAP is ready to make purchases.
    /// </summary>
    public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
    {
        Debug.Log("IAP: Initialized successfully");
        this.controller = controller;
        this.extensions = extensions;
    }

    public void BuyNoAds()
    {
        BuyProductID("noads");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when Unity IAP encounters an unrecoverable initialization error.
    ///
    /// Note that this will not be called if Internet is unavailable; Unity IAP
    /// will attempt initialization until it becomes available.
    /// </summary>
    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnInitializeFailed InitializationFailureReason:" + error);
    }

    public void BuyProductID(string productId)
    {
        productId = gameID + productId;
        if (IsInitialized())
        {
            Product product = controller.products.WithID(productId);

            // If the look up found a product for this device's store and that product is ready to be sold ... 
            if (product != null && product.availableToPurchase)
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("Purchasing product asychronously: '{0}'", product.definition.id));
                // ... buy the product. Expect a response either through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed 
                // asynchronously.
                controller.InitiatePurchase(product);
#if UNITY_EDITOR
                StartCoroutine(DisablePurchaseButton());
#else
                //hide IAP button
                iapButton.SetActive(false);
#endif
                //Do your product logic
                Debug.Log("Ads removed");
                TheGameCtrl.instance.showAds = false;


            }
            else
            {
                // ... report the product look-up failure situation  
                Debug.Log("BuyProductID: FAIL. Not purchasing product, either is not found or is not available for purchase");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // ... report the fact Purchasing has not succeeded initializing yet. Consider waiting longer or 
            // retrying initiailization.
            Debug.Log("BuyProductID FAIL. Not initialized.");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when a purchase completes.
    ///
    /// May be called at any time after OnInitialized().
    /// </summary>
    public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs e)
    {
        bool validPurchase = true; // Presume valid for platforms with no R.V.

        // Unity IAP's validation logic is only included on these platforms.
#if UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX
        // Prepare the validator with the secrets we prepared in the Editor
        // obfuscation window.


        var validator = new CrossPlatformValidator(GooglePlayTangle.Data(),
        AppleTangle.Data(), Application.identifier);

        try
        {
            // On Google Play, result has a single product ID.
            // On Apple stores, receipts contain multiple products.
            var result = validator.Validate(e.purchasedProduct.receipt);
            // For informational purposes, we list the receipt(s)
            Debug.Log("Receipt is valid. Contents:");
            foreach (IPurchaseReceipt productReceipt in result)
            {
                if (productReceipt.productID != e.purchasedProduct.definition.id)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Invalid receipt data");
                    validPurchase = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IAPSecurityException)
        {
            Debug.Log("Invalid receipt, not unlocking content");
            validPurchase = false;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            validPurchase = true;
#endif
        }
#endif

        //apply the purchasing in case if the transaction is valid
        if (validPurchase)
        {
            switch (e.purchasedProduct.definition.id)
            {

                case (gameID + "noads"):
                    Debug.Log("YOU BOUGHT THE NON CONSUMIBLE");
                    TheGameCtrl.instance.showAds = false;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
                    StartCoroutine(DisablePurchaseButton());
#else
                //hide IAP button
                iapButton.SetActive(false);
#endif
                    //Do your product logic
                    break;

            }
        }

        return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when a purchase fails.
    /// </summary>
    public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product p, PurchaseFailureReason r)
    {
        // A product purchase attempt did not succeed. Check failureReason for more detail. Consider sharing 
        // this reason with the user to guide their troubleshooting actions.
        Debug.Log(string.Format("OnPurchaseFailed: FAIL. Product: '{0}', PurchaseFailureReason: {1}", p.definition.storeSpecificId, r));
    }

    // Restore purchases previously made by this customer. Some platforms automatically restore purchases, like Google. 
    // Apple currently requires explicit purchase restoration for IAP, conditionally displaying a password prompt.
    public void RestorePurchases()
    {
        if (!IsInitialized())
        {
            Debug.Log("RestorePurchases FAIL. Not initialized.");
            return;
        }

        // If we are running on an Apple device ... 
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer
                || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.OSXPlayer
                || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.tvOS)
        {
            Debug.Log("RestorePurchases started ...");

            var apple = extensions.GetExtension<IAppleExtensions>();
            // Begin the asynchronous process of restoring purchases. Expect a confirmation response in 
            // the Action below, and ProcessPurchase if there are previously purchased products to restore.
            apple.RestoreTransactions(OnTransactionsRestored);
        }
        else
        {
            // We are not running on an Apple device. No work is necessary to restore purchases.
            Debug.Log("RestorePurchases FAIL. Not supported on this platform. Current = " + Application.platform);
        }
    }

    void OnTransactionsRestored(bool success)
    {
        Debug.Log("Transactions restored " + success.ToString());
    }

    private IEnumerator DisablePurchaseButton()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        iapButton.SetActive(false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Same problem here :(